# How to append to the same location in div every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, append

I am creating an app where you can design a map with images, then save it to a database, then have the database recreate the map in another window. It does this by saving the top and left locations of the images add to the screen. Unfortunately for me, the top and left positions are highly variable.

I have designated an empty div on the page (#draggable) where all appends should occur. I want every image that is added to the constrained box on the page to appear initially at the top left corner (the user can then drag it around). Even if I apply CSS of the object to be left: 0px and top: 0px, it will still put the image next to the last image (with left: 0px and top: 0px), or if the user has dragged the image, it will still be offset from the top left as if there is still an image there.

A demonstration of consecutive placement (all images except for the clearly dragged one show left:0px top:0px when inspected):
https://res.cloudinary.com/the-un-division-network/image/upload/v1555475857/Placement_example.png

I also have an image replacement function, that based upon the results of a form, will replace an image with one of a different color. When these images are added, they veer horribly about 240 pixels to the right and 120 pixels down, and each subsequent form change adds this amount to the next addition:

A demonstration of image replacement results (I do not have +10 rep for images, sorry:
https://res.cloudinary.com/the-un-division-network/image/upload/v1555476283/Image_Replacement_Example.png

I feel as though it should be a display or position style, but all that I have tried have failed.

Here is my edited version of the gracious code from [twisty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463319/twisty) that adds images to the div id=draggable

```
function addImage(u, c, t, left, top) {

                if (u == undefined) {
                    u = "https://res.cloudinary.com/the-un-division-network/image/upload/v1553678772/MainProject/Home.png";
                }
                if (c == undefined) {
                    c == "";
                }
                if (t == undefined) {
                    t = $("#draggable");
                }
                var img = $("<img>", {
                    src: u,
                    class: c,
                }).css({
                    "left" : left + "px",
                    "top" : top + "px",

                });
                img.appendTo(t);

                return img;
            }
```

And then the make-drag function, makes an image draggable

```
function makeDrag(o) {

                o.draggable({
                    containment: "parent",
                    snap: true
                });

            }
```

And here is a snippet of that replaces an image (deletes then adds a new image in what should be the same spot using position.left and position.top)

```
function applyImgCSS(value) {

                var picture = $("#draggable img:last-child");
                var position = picture.position();

                $("#draggable img:last-child").remove();
                if (document.getElementById("saleStatusID").value == "") {

                    switch (value) {
                        case "Empty Lot":
                            {
                                makeDrag(addImage('https://res.cloudinary.com/the-un-division-network/image/upload/v1555457254/MainProject/House-Empty_Lot.png', undefined, undefined, position.left, position.top));
                                break;
                            }
                            //And many more switch statements...
```

Position.top and position.left to my understanding will not give the desired results that I want regardless, but that still doesn't solve the original offset problem.

Open to any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the original code. If we modify `addImage()` to include a `position` we can add that to the CSS. The Drop Zone should have a `position: relative` so that we can set absolute positions inside it relative to it's box model.

```js
$(function() {
  function addImage(u, c, t, p) {
    /***
    Input: URL, Class, Target Object, Position Object
    Output: jQuery Object of IMG element
    ***/
    if (u == undefined) {
      u = "https://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG";
    }
    if (c == undefined) {
      c == "";
    }
    if (t == undefined) {
      t = $("#zone");
    }
    if (p == undefined) {
      p = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      };
    }
    var img = $("<img>", {
      src: u,
      class: c,
    }).css({
      width: "50px",
      height: "100px",
      position: "absolute",
      left: p.left + "px",
      top: p.top + "px"
    });
    img.appendTo(t);
    return img;
  }

  function makeDrag(o) {
    /***
    Input: jQuery Object
    Output: null
    ***/
    o.draggable({
      containment: "parent"
    });
  }

  $("#add-object").click(function() {
    makeDrag(addImage("https://png.pngtree.com/png_detail/20181008/red-brick-wall-png-clipart_1564742.png", "foo"));
  });
});
```

```css
#zone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="add-object">Add Object</button>
<div id="zone"></div>
```

This would accept an Object:

```
{
  top: 0,
  left: 0
}
```

So for example, you could use the following:

```
addImage("https://bricksplayground.webs.com/brick.PNG", "brick", $("#zone"), {top: 10, left: 10});
```

This would create a image at that exact position everytime. The CSS would disrupt the flow and they would appear to be on top of each other instead of side by side when appended to the target.

Hope that helps.